# geometric program with posynomial equality constraints

Tags: convex-optimization, geometric-programming

A geometric program, according to Boyd's textbook, is :

$$
\text{minimize } f_0(x)\\
\text{subject to } f_i(x) \leq 1\\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, h_i(x) = 1
$$

Where $h_i(x)$ are monomials, and $f_i(x)$ are posynomials.

My question is, if you have a constraint where a posynomial equals one, can you still consider this a geometric program? Or is there some transform that ill turn it back into a geometric program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there exists an equality posynomial constraint, the problem is a signomial program.

I believe the posynomial equality constraint can be approximated by an approximating monomial for $x$ close to some $x_0$.

This would transform the program into a geometric program, which one could solve to update $x_0$. One would then have to re-calculate the monomial approximation of the equality constrained posynomial, and repeat the process until $x_0$ converges.

There is no guarantee for convergence to global minimum in this solution though, so I am open to a more informative answer!

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of this iterative update procedure